# How do I display line breaks from a text-area in a table?

Tags: webforms, 9

I have a webform with a text-area field. I want to display the submitted values in a custom table.

I am using this code to be able to display line breaks, and keep the input secure.

```php
$rows[] = ['Questions', Markup::create(nl2br(Html::escape($data['question'])))];
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: So this is actually working?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working. Tested with line break and <script> tag.